# Running NodeJs binary with scratch Docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, binary, dockerfile, alpine-linux

We can convert NodeJs applications into binaries with the [`pkg` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg). I want to build the binary and run the same with the Docker `scratch` image.

`index.js`

```js
const http = require('http')
http.createServer().listen(3000)
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:10 as build

COPY index.js .
RUN npm i pkg -g && pkg -t node10-alpine-x64 index.js

FROM scratch
COPY --from=build index /index

ENTRYPOINT ["/index"]
```

When I run `docker build -t index . && docker run --rm -it index`, I get this error message - `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scratch` is an empty image with no files at all, your binary may have dependencies and expect certain linux environment. Try to use minimal linux base images instead of scratch - `alpine`, `debian`, `ubuntu`.

Answer (score 2):

I think @Isanych is right, as `scratch` is good to run c++, go binaries but I did not find a way to run `pkg` executable file on `scratch` image, so here is the solution that is based on alpine, but alpine still needs some dependency that is mentioned [here](https://medium.com/@evenchange4/deploy-a-commercial-next-js-application-with-pkg-and-docker-5c73d4af2ee), and it's working with below image

You can try this

```
FROM node:10 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY index.js .
RUN npm i pkg -g
RUN pkg -t node10-alpine-x64 index.js
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache libstdc++ libgcc
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/ .
CMD ["./index"]
```

**Bonus:** your image is still below then 50 MB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use distroless Node.js images like https://github.com/astefanutti/scratch-node as based image, e.g.:

```
FROM node as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json index.js ./
RUN npm install --prod

FROM astefanutti/scratch-node
COPY --from=builder /app /
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "index.js"]
```

The size of the Node 16 base image is 17.1 MB compressed.